# How to testing function with Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

Help to test the function

```
export function trulyPipeOfObject<T>(value: Observable<T>): Observable<T | Record<string, unknown>> {
  return value.pipe(
    map((item: T): T | Record<string, unknown> => item || {}),
    catchError(() => of({})),
  );
}
```

I don't know where to start. I don't understand what kind of mock data can be used.

```
describe('File: rx.utils.ts', () => {
  describe('Function: trulyPipeOfObject', () => {
    it('Return', () => {

      void expect(trulyPipeOfObject()).toBe();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question. But if you want to test an Observable, you can just subscribe to it in your spec.

```
// one way to create an Observable is to use the `of` method from RxJS
    // const observable = of({ name: "John Doe", age: 25 })

    // another way to create an Observable is to use the `Observable` constructor
    const observable = new Observable((observer) => {
        observer.next({ name: "John Doe", age: 25 });
    });

    trulyPipeOfObject(observable)
        .subscribe((item) => {
            expect(item).toEqual({ name: "John Doe", age: 25 });
        });
```